# Show or hide a table row based on a Radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple jQuery code below that shows or hides a bunch of table rows depending on the value of 2 radio buttons.

The code below works great for the click event but I would also like to add in code that work when the page is loaded, before the click event ever happens it should show or hide my table rows based on the value of the radio button.

So when page loads, if the radio button for the "yes" value is selected it should show the tables, if no then it should hide them.  IF no radio button is selected, it should also hide them.

Can someone help to add these additions?

```
$('input[type=\"radio\"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('value')=='yes'){
        $('.showCta').show();
    }
    if($(this).attr('value')=='no'){
        $('.showCta').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answers posted so far work, I'd still advise further changes to condense your code a little (you're using jQuery, the slogan for which is: "write less, do more." Take advantage of that):

```
// You don't need to escape the quotes (unless you delimit the string with
// the same quotes you use within your string).
// bind event-handling to the 'change' event:
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    // because this should only execute according the condition of the
    // checked 'input' element:
    if (this.checked){
        // show, or hide, the element(s) according to the assessment evaluating
        // to true (show) or false (hide):
        $('.showCta').toggle(this.value === 'yes');
    }
// trigger the change event, and thus the change-event handling, on page-load:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/859bLuaj/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Thanks I like it.  I should've mentioned it is escaped because it is part of a single quote PHP string.

Comment: @jason: you're very very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped; and while I *assumed* there was a deliberate reason for the escaping, I wasn't quite sure (and escaping doesn't break anything, it just looks a little... *odd*).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the main logic in an function like bellow, This is because you won't repeat your code.

```
function showTablesByRadio(){
    if($(this).attr('value')=='yes'){
        $('.showCta').show();
    }
    if($(this).attr('value')=='no'){
        $('.showCta').hide();
    }
}
```

call That function on click of radio & for each radio on load.

```
$('input[type=\"radio\"]').click(showTablesByRadio);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=\"radio\"]').each(showTablesByRadio);
})
```

Comment: Will `$('input[type=\"radio\"]').click(showTablesByRadio);` work outside document ready?

Comment: That approach takes no account of whether the `<input>` is checked, or not, and will fail as soon as a non-checked (but still with a `value` property) `<input>` is encountered *after* a *`checked`* `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val()` and `change` event. Also you don't need to escape quotes like `\"`

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change (function(){
    if($(this).val() =='yes'){
        $('.showCta').show();
    }
    if($(this).val() == 'no'){
        $('.showCta').hide();
    }
}).change(); //Trigger intially
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a pretty simple fix since all the current code you have should still work.  Try this:

The following handles the on page ready:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var $x = $('input[type=\"radio\"]');

  if($x.attr('value')=='yes'){
            $('.showCta').show();
  }
  if($x.attr('value')=='no'){
            $('.showCta').hide();
  }
});
```

And keep the event handler as well:

```
$('input[type=\"radio\"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('value')=='yes'){
        $('.showCta').show();
    }
    if($(this).attr('value')=='no'){
        $('.showCta').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Looking at the other answers, they're much better.  ie.  It's better to trigger the click event manually, so you're only dealing with 1 code source.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this:

HTML:

```
<input id='yes' type='radio' name='check' checked>Yes</input>
<input id='no' type='radio' name='check'>No</input>
<button id='button'>Button</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('yes').checked) {
        $('#button').show();
    } else {
        $('#button').hide();
    }
});
```